# Value of cos 1 (angle is in radians)?

Tags: trigonometry, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers, rationality-testing

How can we calculate the value of $\cos 1$ where the angle is in radians (and not degrees). If this isn't possible, can we somehow find whether this value would be rational or irrational?

P.S: I know how to determine the irrationality of $\cos 1$ when angle is in degrees, and also am aware of its explicit formula. But those methods cannot be used here.

Comment: $1$ in radian is $\frac{180^\circ}\pi$.

Comment: I think you could probably prove this is irrational similarly to how you would prove $e$ is irrational.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/677900/proof-that-cos1-is-transcendental) might help.

Comment: For numerical value, use the rapidly-convergent series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n/(2n)!$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the value of any $ \cos x $ via [a power series](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_series):

$ \cos x = x-\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}-\frac{x^6}{6!}+\frac{x^8}{8!}... $

This can be rewritten as:

$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!} $

And solved by painstaking summation to calculate that $ \cos1 \approx 0.540 $.

Comment: $\pi=3.1415...Rad$ ⇒ $\frac {\pi}{3.1415..}=1 $ ⇒$cos 1>cos\frac{\pi}{3}=0.5$

Comment: I agree, as my answer shows.

Comment: If you know an angle close-by with easy trig values, then use the trig. angle addition theorem to get a faster series approximation, $$\cos 1=\cos(\fracπ3)\cos(\fracπ3-1)+\sin(\fracπ3)\sin(\fracπ3-1)=\frac12\cos(\fracπ3-1)+\frac{\sqrt3}2\sin(\fracπ3-1).$$

Comment: Just because something can be expressed as an infinite sum of rationals doesn’t make it rational. $\pi^2/6=1+1/4+1/9+\ldots$, which is certainly not rational.

Comment: @csch2, indeed. In fact, $\cos 1$ is irrational as a consequence of, say, [Lindemann's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindemann%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem) (idea outlined [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/xh6r4/sinxy_for_rational_numbers/c5mbc1c?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x)).

Comment: Can you explain what you mean when you say "solved via differentiating"?  It's not clear to me how the link helps.  Did you use differentiation in some way to obtain the approximation 0.540, and in what way is this better than just letting $x=1$ and summing many terms of the original series?

Answer (score 1):

We may approximate as follows:

$1 Rad ≈ \frac{\pi}{3.15}=\frac{\pi}{3}\times \frac{1}{1,05}$

$1.05=\frac{100}{105}=\frac{105-5}{105}=1-\frac{1}{21}$

$1 Rad= \frac {\pi}{3}-\frac{\pi}{63}$

$cos(\frac {\pi}{3}-\frac{\pi}{63})=cos\frac {\pi}{3}cos\frac{\pi}{63}+sin\frac {\pi}{3}sin\frac{\pi}{63} ≈0.499+0.043=0.542$